# Element not click-able (Selenium Webdriver - JAVA)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

All,

I have been working with Selenium webdriver for some time and I got into a strange problem. I need to click an element which selenium webdriver is not doing so all of my next steps fail. The html of the element is as follows.

```
<div id="group-container" class="grp-view-container">

<div id="group-container-0" class="component-inline-block" '="" data-original-title="" title="">

<div id="group-container-1" class="component-inline-block" '="" data-original-title="" title="">

</div>
```

I need to click on group-container-1. I have used a simple click, Actiions, JavascriptExecutor, SendKeys(keys.RETURN).

I used Chromedriver, FirefoxDriver.

Please guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: You should give some of your code,or at least the part of the html containing your elements :)

Comment: yes plz provide some source code of the problem area

Comment: <div id="group-container" class="grp-view-container">

<div id="group-container-0" class="component-inline-block" '="" data-original-title="" title="">

<div id="group-container-1" class="component-inline-block" '="" data-original-title="" title="">

</div>

Comment: @rajNishKuMar Please review the html

Comment: Your group-container-1 has no "onClick" event handler. Add something like   <div .. class="group-container-1" onClikc="window.alert("Alert");".. </div>, and see if you see any alerts

Comment: @BorislavStoilov I do see alert when I add an onClick event in group-container-1

Answer (score 2):

This sort of situation often arises when you have CSS that make use of the z-index. A transparent portion of another HTML element maybe covering the HTML element of interest to you.

Sometimes the same situation may arise when you use absolute positioning.

Comment: I think once the element is located by selenium it doesn't matter if its hidden under another element.

Comment: @BorislavStoilov unfortunately that is not so, an element cannot be clicked if it's covered by another element. You can confirm this for youself for example by using a jquery modal.

Comment: @e4c5 are you sure, I might be wrong but take a look at http://pastie.org/10805286 . I have 2 overlying divs.                                    'var d =document.getElementById("red");  d.click();' Gives me 'red' even thought black is over it

Comment: @BorislavStoilov on that link nothing is clickable to me, or am I missing something?

Comment: You need to run that HTML in a browser.

Comment: @BorislavStoilov but what's at issue here is not whether you are able to click on something or not. It's about selenium being able to click on something. But selenium cannot click something that's covered.

Comment: @BorislavStoilov also , FYI,  when run on the browser, I only get black in the console. Chrome 49.0.2623.112 (64-bit)

Comment: var d =document.getElementById("red"); d.click(); This will give you "red" even though red is under black.

Comment: @BorislavStoilov ho well, no point in our arguing over this. the OP doesn't seem to have any interest :)

Comment: @BorislavStoilov Please tell what should I do or do I need to ask the developer to add something for me in the html? I am new to this.

Comment: @e4c5 Sorry, I have tons of work to finish. And this is kind of a blocker.

Comment: @e4c5 I am terribly sorry. I accidently edited your post please ignore me :)

Comment: @BorislavStoilov no worries.

Comment: @BorislavStoilov someone else had approved your edit. I rolled it back and up voted your answer.

Comment: Thanks for this @e4c5

Comment: If the answer proved usefull, please be so kind as to accept it so that a person who lands on this page in the future knows what to do. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After some google search and local test, I came to the conclusion that indeed if and element is hidden behind another element, the normal element.click() call from selenium won't work.

In your case, you probably have some css that hides the you element behind other elements, thus making it unreachable for Selenium.

In this case you should use plain old JS.

Here is an example with FireFoxDriver:

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("ENTER YOU URL HERE");
// driver.findElement(By.id("group-container-1")).click(); This will work only if the element is not hidden.

String jsExpression = "document.getElementById('group-container-1').click();";
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(jsExpression);
```

To see any result you must have onClick listener on the clicked element though.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue in the past when I was writing a script to test a search field. The script worked on the page header but not the footer. I could also test the field by key entry (`sendKeys`) just not mouse click.

I got this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <input type="submit" class="submit hidden-text" value="Search"> is not clickable at point (988, 633). Other element would receive the click: <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></i>
```

My ScreenShotOnFailure.java utility showed the problem:
[image: back to top button obscuring search icon]

A button taking the using 'back to the top' of the page partially obscured the search icon I wanted to click. I initially tried to get around this by specifying the window size (`driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1024, 768));`) as I assumed it was being obscured due to the browser dimensions but that didn't help. So I made the switch to JS to click the button.

I changed:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@value='Search'])[2]")).click();
```

to:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@value='Search'])[2]"));
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);
```

(and imported the relevant imports)